# Factorise $x^4 - 3x^3 - 41x - 45 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring

The answer is $(x^2 - 4x - 5)(x^2 + x + 9)$ but I don't know how to get there.

As a solution I tried this. Write the polynomial as:

$(x^2 + Ax + B)(x^2 + Cx + D) = 0$

Then equate powers of $x$ and solve the following system:

$x^3: A + C = -3$

$x^2: AC + D + B = 0$

$x^1: AD + BC = -41$

$x^0: BD = -45$

As far as I can see, this system of linear equations, produces a more complicated polynomial.

Comment: Did you spend time trying to work it out? And if so, how much time, and what did you try?  Or did you look at the question and immediately then the solution, and give up right away?  Please add any details recording your efforts, and where, exactly, you get stuck.

Comment: Note that $-1$ and $5$ are roots.

Comment: Notice that the first factor in the solution is $(x-5)(x+1)$.

Comment: @amWhy I did. See update.

Comment: Thanks for updating, s5s.

Comment: What is your problem now? You have 4 equations with 4 unknowns

Comment: Must be some mistake, in your assumed form there is no $A$, but it does appear in the system...

Comment: I assume that the first quadratic is $x^2+Ax+B$

Comment: @Andrei yes, fixed.

Comment: Why do you assume it factors as $(x^2 + Ax + B)(x^2 + Cx + D)$ rather that $(x+A)(x^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D)$ (where $x^2 + Bx^2 + Cx + D)$ may or may not factor further) or doesn't factor and all.

Comment: "this system of linear equations"  For the record that is not a system of *linear* equations.

Comment: One might get there, haphazardly but without much calculation, by noticing that $-1$ is a root, so the polynomial must be divisible by $x + 1,$ and the quotient is quickly found to be $x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x - 45,$ which one might notice is $x(x - 2)^2 - 45,$ whereupon the fact that $5$ is another root leaps to the eye.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we find the roots $5$ and $-1$ so that the polynomial factors as
$$
(x^2 + x + 9)(x + 1)(x - 5).
$$
The only confusion here with our answer is that $x^2 - 4x - 5$ is not irreducible but still decomposes into two linear factors. Dividing them out you don't have to make the computation $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ any longer.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If the idea is to find integer factors, note that the free term $45$, must be the product of the individual roots, so you can get a clue by factoring it. Note $45 = 5\cdot 9 = 5 \cdot 3^2$, so it makes sense to try plugging in $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 9, \pm 15$.

If when you plug in a value $v$, you do get zero, the polynomial should factor by $x-v$.

---

**UPDATE**

So you end up with the system
$$
\begin{split}
A + C &= -3\\
AC + D + B &= 0\\
AD + BC &= -41\\
BD &= -45
\end{split}
$$
You can solve it by elimination. For example, from the first equation, you have $A = -3-C$ and from the last equation, you have $B = -45/D$. Plugging those into the other two equations will yield two equations in two unknowns...

Answer (score 0):

$A+C = -3$ means $A = -(C+3)$

$BD = -45$ means $B=-\frac {45}D$

So

$AC + D+B =0$ means

$-(C+3)C + D -\frac {45}D =0$ means

$C^2 + 3C +(\frac {45}D-D)$ or that

$C = \frac {-3\pm \sqrt{9 + 4(D-\frac{45}D)}2$

Now we presumed that this *could* be factored so $D$ is an integer that divides $45$ and $9 + 4(D-\frac {45}D) \ge 0$.

If $|D|= 1$ then $0 \le 9+4(D-\frac {45}D)= 9+4(45-1)=185$ which is not a perfect square.

If $|D|=3$ then $0 \le 9+4(D-\frac {45}D) =9+4(15-3)=57$ which is not a perfect square.

If $|D|=5$ then $0 \le 9+ 4(9-5)=25= 5^2$.

So $D=-5$.

By symmetry, we know $D=\frac{45}{-5} = 9$ will yield same result and $|D| = 15, 45$ the same non results.

So $D = -5$ or $9$ and $B = 9$ or $-5$

And $C =\frac {-3 \pm \sqrt {25}}2= -4, or $1$.

Wolog we will do $D=-5$ and $B=9$.

The fourth equation is

$AD + BC =-41$ which give us

$-(C+3)(-5) + 9C = -41$

So $14C = -56$ or $C = -4$.

And that gives us $A=-(-4+3)=1$.

So $x^4 - 3x^3 - 41x -45 = (x^2 + x +9)(x -4x -5)$

.......

But for heck sake, why didn't you just use the rational root theorem?

If $x = -1$ then $x^4 - 3x^3 -41x -45=1+3+41-45=0$ so $(x+1)$ is a factor so $x^4-3x^3 -41x -45 = x^3(x+1) - 4x^3 - 41x -45=$

$x^3(x+1)- 4x^2(x+1) + 4x^2-41x -45=$

$x^3(x+1)-4x^2(x+1) + 4x(x+1) -45x-45=$

$x^3(x+1) - 4x^2(x+1) + 4x(x+1) - 45(x+1)=$

$(x+1)(x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x -45)$.

And the find $x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x -45=0$ for integer $x$ would mean

$x^3 + 4x = 4x^2+45$ would require $x>0$ and $x|45$ simple trial would have $x=5$.  So $x-5$ is a factor and

$x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x -45 = x^2(x-5) +x^2 +4x -45=$

$x^2(x-5) + x(x-5) + 9x - 45=$

$x^2(x-5) + x(x-5) + 9(x-5)=$

$(x-5)(x^2 +x + 9)$

So $x^4-3x^3 -41x -45=(x+1)(x-5)(x^2 + x +9)$.

No by the rational root theorem the rational roots of $x^2 + x +9$ must be $x =\pm 1, \pm 3$ and it's obvious none of those work.  (Also by the quadratic formula $x =\frac {-1\pm\sqrt{1^2 -4*9}}2$ is not real, let only rational.)

So that's the complete factorization $x^4-3x^3 -41x -45=(x+1)(x-5)(x^2 + x +9)$